# Telethon cannot forward message even "sensitive_enabled" is disabled

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm using Telethon to forward messages from A group to B channel. But some of the documents were not able to be forwarded with the following log:

```
restriction_reason=[
      RestrictionReason(platform='ios',
      reason='porn', text="This message couldn't be displayed on your device because it contains pornographic materials.")
    ]
```

So I use `functions.account.GetContentSettingsRequest()` to check my setting and here is the result:

> ContentSettings(sensitive_enabled=False, sensitive_can_change=True)

I `looks like` the sensitive content lock has been disabled, but how can I still get this restriction message?

Does someone encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Other than the settings for sensitive content, Telegram abides by local laws as well. So if your number belongs to a country or area that forbids porn content, Telegram will block such content for your account. Also any channels or groups created by that number and publishing illegal content will be closed.

So if you're forwarding a message that is known as a porn content to a destination account with a number belonging to an area with laws against porn, that message won't be shown for that destination.

Comment: wow, that's actually pretty cool